# export SHAP waterfall plot to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, neural-network, shap

I am working on a binary classification using random forest model, neural networks in which am using SHAP to explain the model predictions. I followed the tutorial and wrote the below code to get the waterfall plot shown below

```
row_to_show = 20
data_for_prediction = ord_test_t.iloc[row_to_show]  # use 1 row of data here. Could use multiple rows if desired
data_for_prediction_array = data_for_prediction.values.reshape(1, -1)
rf_boruta.predict_proba(data_for_prediction_array)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf_boruta)
# Calculate Shap values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(data_for_prediction)
shap.plots._waterfall.waterfall_legacy(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0],ord_test_t.iloc[row_to_show])
```

This generated the plot as shown below

[image]

However, I want to export this to dataframe and how can I do it?

I expect my output to be like as shown below. I want to export this for the full dataframe. Can you help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a small experiment:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from shap import TreeExplainer

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=100).fit(X, y)
explainer = TreeExplainer(model)
```

What is `explainer` here? If you do `dir(explainer)` you'll find out it has some methods and attributes among which is:

```
explainer.expected_value
```

which is of interest to you because this is base on which SHAP values add up.

Furthermore:

```
sv = explainer.shap_values(X)
len(sv)
```

will give a hint `sv` is a list consisting of 2 objects which are most probably SHAP values for `1` and `0`, which must be symmetric (because what moves towards 1 moves exactly by the same amount, but with opposite sign, towards `0`).

Hence:

```
sv1 = sv[1]
```

Now you have everything to pack it to the desired format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sv1, columns=X.columns)
df.insert(0, 'bv', explainer.expected_value[1])
```

---

**Q**: How do I know?
**A**: Read docs and source code.

Comment: When you do 'sv[1], does it get shap value for class 1 or class 0? Orbit isbjust index position?, because we want shap values of class 1.

Comment: These are SV for class 1.

Comment: One thing is, I realized that when we put shap values in dataframe (`df`), it loses the indices. How do we know then which row belongs to which record in X?

Comment: Should we assume that it's in the same order (shap df) as our input dataframe (which is X)?... If my X dataframe first row (starts with an index of 14), am I right to understand that index 0 in shap df belongs to index 14 of input dataframe?

Comment: I believe it's not an assumption but the way it works: if you put your data to Pandas df, the order is preserved.

Comment: Is it okay to compute shapley values for train datset as well? to see whether the explanations are consistent across train and test?

Comment: Or is it not logical or conceptually right to compare shapley values across train and test? I see that you have used the full datset `X`.

Comment: I've used X for the sake of simplicity (to be honest, I started with a full example from my notes and deleted train/test split). Conceptully, I would use X_train to "train" explainer (or infer shapley marginal contributions), and use it for test to explain some peculiarities in data, e.g. "why this 2 simingly similar datapoints were classified as 0 and 1". But nothing prevents you from using trained model (trained trees, without any background) to extract information like "what was important for model and what wasn't so important". Depends on the question to be answered.

Comment: Beware this is my opinion.

Comment: Do you know how can we get the feature values in waterfall plot (and export it to dataframe) along with shap values? I can create a new post if you want. Do you think it is possible to get variable name, with its value and the shap value?

Comment: Add a question and desired output. Note, you're asking 2 values for a row and a column: feature value and shap value. I would think about a tuple, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, you can do something like this with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
    
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(data_for_prediction)
shap_values_df = pd.DataFrame(shap_values)
```

to get the feature names, you should do something like this (if `data_for_prediction` is a dataframe):

```
feature_names = data_for_prediction.columns.tolist()
shap_df = pd.DataFrame(shap_values.values, columns=feature_names)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Upvoted. Can you show me how can we get the base value, shap value and feature name  along with row index?

Comment: Currentky, your code guves only shap value and features?, how can I get the base valir and row ids?

Comment: @TheGreat I don't have an example to run right now, I edited the post. Let me now if with the update there are some improvements for what you want

Comment: But your code doesn't get base value. Right? It only gets shap values?

Comment: @TheGreat if you mean the base features values, you should do a concat of the dataframe with shapvalues with your original data, doing a reshape if necessary pd.concat([base_values, shap_values_df], axis=1)

or a join with the instance id

Comment: I got an error - `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'feature_names'`

Comment: I also got another error - `ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(2, 60, 4)`

Comment: @TheGreat, sorry, you can extract the feature names from the data_for_prediction (if it is a dataframe). Simply type data_for_prediction.columns.tolist()

as stated here: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/268

Answer (score 1):

I'm a currenty using that :

```
def getShapReport(classifier,X_test):
   shap_values = shap.TreeExplainer(classifier).shap_values(X_test)
   shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
   shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test)
   return pd.DataFrame(shap_values[1])
```

It first displays the shap values for the model, and for each prediction after that, and finally it returns the dataframe for the positive class(i'm on an imbalance context)

It is for a Tree explainer and not a waterfall, but it is basically the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Upvoted. Yes, am working on imbalanced data as well and need to find for positive class (label 1). Your code also does the same? Can you also show in your code, how can we get the base value for each instance/row along with shapley value?

Comment: Pandas keep the index, so you can basicaly (pandas.)concat your shapley values and you prediction set to match feature values and feature importance

Comment: Thanks but my comment is based on shapley base/expected value. It is different from feature SHAP value

Comment: I don't get it right. The "by row" shapley values is based on predict, if you want "base" row values, you need to predict on test, just to compute it. 
Or if i'm not wrong on some models like lgbm, you can ask the model to compute it, not sure if it's available on train.

Comment: If you look at my expected output, I would like to get the feature importance and base value for test data dataframe

Comment: Oh yes sorry i'm slow... you already got the feature importance from our two answers, but the base value idk, maybe class weight... or average of the training phase. 
I don't know, i don't want to give you wrong infos :(

Comment: Do you think, you can help with this? I rephrased my problem differently - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696039/store-np-float64-and-np-array-values-as-column-values-in-dataframe