# Store np.float64 and np.array values as column values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have two numpy arrays and dataframe as given below

```
val = np.array([0.501,0.32])
values = np.arange(24).reshape((2,3,4))
input_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['colname_' + str(i) for i in range(4)])
```

I would like to

a) Create a new dataframe (dummy) with 3 columns such as `ROW_ID`, `FEATURE NAME`, `Contribution`

b) values for dummy dataframe should be populated using `np.array` above and `column names from` input_df`

c) Under the `Feature Name` column use the input_df column names

b) Populate the `val[0]` as `contribution` in dummy dataframe and also use each element from `values[0][1]` to populate it in `contribution` column.
I tried the below code

```
pd.DataFrame({
        "Feature Name": ["Base value"] + [f"{col}" for col in df.columns.tolist()],
        "Contribution": (val[0].tolist()) + list(values[0][1])
    })
```

But I get an error message

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'

Or I also receive another error which is

> ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

**update - real data issue**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
pd.DataFrame({
  "Feature Name": ["Base value"] + [f"{col}" for col in df.columns.tolist()],
  "Contribution": (val[:1].tolist()) + list(values[0][1])
  #                   ^^^^
})
```

`val[0]` makes it a scalar value, even followed by `.tolist()`

```py
>>> type(val[0].tolist())
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted for the help. what does val[:1] mean? It takes all values upto index 1?

Comment: Correct. It slices the list with the first element. You could also do `[val[0]]`

Comment: You don't need that extra `[]` around `(explainer.expected_value[:1].tolist())`, it's already been a list. Same for the latter part `shape_values[0][1]`.

Comment: I missed a list function. thanks for your help. It worked

Comment: Do you know how can I do this for multiple rows in dataframe of 2000 rows? Currently, we did for one row only (ROW_ID = 20). We need to do similarly for 1999 rows. Can you help me with it? I will open a new question?

Comment: Yep. Please open a new question and state where your ROW_ID is coming from. Maybe @ me and I will get notified when you post it.

Comment: Here it is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696812/iterate-over-numpy-arrays-to-fill-pandas-dataframe