# iterate over numpy arrays to fill pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have two numpy arrays and dataframe as given below

```
val = np.array([0.501,0.32])
values = np.arange(24).reshape((2,3,4))
input_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['colname_' + str(i) for i in range(4)])
row_id_list = [20,40]
```

I would like to

a) Create a new dataframe (dummy) with 3 columns such as `ROW_ID`, `FEATURE NAME`, `Contribution`

b) values for dummy dataframe should be populated using `np.array` above and `column names from` input_df`

c) Under the `Feature Name` column use the input_df column names

b) Populate the `val[0]` as `contribution` in dummy dataframe and also use each element from `values[0][1]` to populate it in `contribution` column.

I tried the below code with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696039/store-np-float64-and-np-array-values-as-column-values-in-dataframe)

```
   pd.DataFrame({
  "Feature Name": ["Base value"] + [f"{col}" for col in df.columns.tolist()],
  "Contribution": (val[:1].tolist()) + list(values[0][1])
  #                   ^^^^
})
```

I was trying something like below

```
for i in range(len(input_df )):
    print("explainer value is")
    print(val[:1].tolist())
    print("the values are")
    print(values[0][i].tolist())
```

While this does for a single row, I would like to do this for 2000 rows. Is there any efficient way to do this?

[image]

Comment: for each row, we have to fill rows, `base_value` and number of columns available in input dataframe

Comment: How is the ROW_ID associated with your data? Each ROW_ID is associated with a value in `val`? How about `values`?