# SHAP plotting waterfall using an index value in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, classification, shap

I am working on a binary classification using random forest algorithm

Currently, am trying to explain the model predictions using SHAP values.

So, I referred this useful post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688298/export-shap-waterfall-plot-to-dataframe) and tried the below.

```
from shap import TreeExplainer, Explanation
from shap.plots import waterfall
sv = explainer(ord_test_t)
exp = Explanation(sv.values[:,:,1], 
                  sv.base_values[:,1], 
                  data=ord_test_t.values, 
                  feature_names=ord_test_t.columns)
idx = 20
waterfall(exp[idx])
```

I like the above approach as it allows to display the feature values along with waterfall plot. So, I wish to use this approach

However, this doesn't help me get the waterfall for a specific row in `ord_test_t` (test data).

For example, let's consider that `ord_test_t.Index.tolist()` returns 3,5,8,9 etc...

Now, I want to plot the waterfall plot for `ord_test_t.iloc[[9]]` but when I pass exp[9], it just gets the 9th row but not the index named as 9.

When I try `exp.iloc[[9]]` it throws error as `explanation object doesnt have iloc`.

Can help me with this please?

Comment: What model do you use? LGB, XGB, RF?

Comment: I built my classification model using random forest algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is as following:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from shap import TreeExplainer, Explanation
from shap.plots import waterfall

import shap

print(shap.__version__)

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

idx = 9
model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=100).fit(X, y)
explainer = TreeExplainer(model)
sv = explainer(X.loc[[idx]])    # corrected, pass the row of interest as df
exp = Explanation(
    sv.values[:, :, 1],         # class to explain
    sv.base_values[:, 1],
    data=X.loc[[idx]].values,   # corrected, pass the row of interest as df
    feature_names=X.columns,
)
waterfall(exp[0])               # pretend you have only 1 data point which is 0th
```

---

```
0.40.0
```

[image]

Proof:

```
model.predict_proba(X.loc[[idx]]) # corrected
```

---

```
array([[0.95752656, 0.04247344]])
```

Comment: One quick question. For display purpose, is it okay if i switch the sign of values? For ex: my business wants to have negative sign for positive outcome (minority cass of interest)

Comment: And positive sign for majority class. Of course, model will work towards predictingclass 1 (minority class) bit i wish to change signs alonebut retain the shap value as it is. So, final probability becomes 1 - P

Comment: is it okay to do this way?

Comment: It sounds to me as if you want substitute class `1` for class `0`. Why not do it this way?

Comment: but that will degrade the model performance because as you may know that some models metrics like precisin, recall, etc focus on optimizing towards class positive (majority) only. You can read more about this in the url linked. They say inverting label is the best option.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563545/why-metrics-focus-on-maximizing-only-majority-class-in-binary-classification

Comment: I don't want to change the model working. but change the display. Is it okay to change the display based on the logic that I gave above in comments (as I don;t wish to change the labels for model and retrain)?

Comment: Predicting on imbalanced data is a different topic. RF per se is not very well suited for imbalanced data. And flipping labels will definately not improve model performance in terms of AUC e.g. My point is that manually changing sign might be misleading for users of your analysis. But if you have solid foundation for the idea why not.

Comment: Sorry. May i check what do you mean by solid foundation? Just wish to invert the signs in shap dataframe? And do the final prediction 1-P.

Comment: I personally favor full discliosure and showing results "as is". If you want to explain opposite class, I would explicitely flip the labels, tune the model accordingly by maximizing the metrics of choice, and show SHAP "as is". If you definitely know that the sign must be opposite of what you observe.

Comment: But it might depend on the exact wording of what you want. Why not.

Comment: I just realized that I don;t have to do much work to alter the display (for invert label purpose). I just have to get the SHAP values for class 0 (so, the sign is inverted automatically via package itself). I just have to make sure to update the final probability alone (1-P). Am I right?

Comment: SV for binary -- yes. Base values might be different depending on model.

Comment: Yes, agree. If I had built a model to focus on optimizing class 0 predictions, the base value will change etc. but for the sake of display purpose, if I just invert (and show the base value) do you think it is incorrect? Business wants to invert the display but am stuck between business decision or data science principle. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Man, feel sorry. Given your latest question, I have to correct myself: `df.iloc[[99]]` should change to `df.loc[[99]]`. Sorry again